# Update column values with dynamically created JSON MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, json, sql-update, inner-join

I have a `Relationships` table that looks something like this

```
ID | FromID | ToID | JsonPair
1      10      8       null
2      11      13      null
3      15      21      null
4      26      22      null
```

And 2 tables `From` and `To`

```
FromID | FromName                   ToID | ToName
  1        'A'                       1      'Z'                 
  2        'B'                       2      'Y' 
 ...                                ...
  10       'E'                       8      'M'                        
  11       'I'                      ...
 ...                                 13     'N'                        
  15       'O'                      ...
 ...                                 21     'F'                        
  26       'U'                       22     'H'
```

I'm trying to update the JsonPair column with Json objects in the form `{FromName: ToName}`. So the resulting table would look like

```
ID | FromID | ToID | JsonPair
1      10      8     {'E':'M'}
2      11      13    {'I':'N'}
3      15      21    {'O':'F'}
4      26      22    {'U':'H'}
```

I'm a novice at SQL. I'm thinking that I should `SELECT` the names first, then use the result to put in the `UPDATE` statement.

So far I got this to return FromName and ToName

```
SELECT F.FromName FROM Relationships AS R
JOIN From as F
ON R.FromID = F.FromID
```

and

```
SELECT T.ToName FROM Relationships AS R
JOIN To as T
ON R.FromID = T.FromID;
```

Then I think I should use the result of this to do

```
UPDATE Relationships
SET JsonPair = (combine result above and format to json)
WHERE JsonPair IS NULL;
```

I'm stuck at the combining and format step. Can I get help with this please?

I'm using `MySql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  update/join syntax, along with `json_object()`.

Consider:

```
update relationships r
inner join t_from f on f.fromid = r.fromid
inner join t_to   t on t.to_id  = r.to_id
set r.jsonpair = json_object(f.fromname, t.toname)
```

Note: `from` and `to` are [reserved words in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), hence bad choices for table names. I renamed them to `t_from`  and `t_to` in the query.

Comment: Thank you! Yes in my project they are named differently so that shouldn't be an issue, but I didn't know that either.